# How to get data from a Class

Tags: python, class

```
class Beers:

    def __init__(beer, name):
        beer.name = name

    def beer_data(beer, type, price, size, packs):
        beer.type = type
        beer.price = price
        beer.size = size
        beer.packs = packs

    def beer_additional_data(beer):
        beer.data_List = []
        beer.data_List += beer.name, beer.size*beer.packs

hjnakken = Beers('Hjnakken')
bidwsr = Beers('Bidwsr')
cirona = Beers('Cirona')

hjnakken.beer_data('Pale lager', 2.3, 6, 12)
bidwsr.beer_data('American lager', 2.0, 8, 10)
cirona.beer_data('Pale lager', 2.6, 8, 6)

hjnakken.beer_additional_data()
bidwsr.beer_additional_data()
cirona.beer_additional_data()

which_beer = input('Enter beer name: ')
```

How to do this (below) without an if statement? What is the pythonic way?

```
print(which_beer.data_List)
```

I want to get the `XYZ.data_List` after a user input.

1. so find if input is valid (match with `beer.name`)
2. print or work further with the `XYZ.data_List`

Comment: All your methods are missing the first arguments `self`. I see you used `beer` instead, but it is convention to name the arguments `self`.

Comment: Put your beers in a dictionary with the type as the key.

Comment: Klaus D., next time i'll use self... I thought it's not that important. THX! :D

Comment: You hava a logic problem: `beer.data_List = []` can't be inside `class Beers` as your `class Beers` describes **ONE** type of **Beer**.

Comment: Alex Hall: I think it is more simple with tuples, dicts and so on, but I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this with classes as well... :)

Comment: stovfl: but beer.data_List only describes ONE type of Beer.  So Hjnakken.data_List = ['Hjnakken', 72] ...

Comment: @ifigazsi *"describes ONE type of Beer"*: Naming confusion, `Beers`  == **ONE name of Beer**. All data in `def beer_data(...` have to be a **own** `class object`, e.g. `class BeerType:`. These objects have to appended to `beer.data_List`.

Comment: @stovfl: ok i got your point and probably it is right... but what is the answer to my question? :D

Comment: @ifigazsi *"I want to get the XYZ.data_List after a user input."*: It's not possible, as your `class Beers` objects are **not** in a searchable `sequence` object.

Comment: @stovfl: its quite sad... :*(, but thanks, and need to find a different way around... with 'if'-s i guess...

Comment: @ifigazsi: **Why don't you want to use a `sequence` object?**

Comment: @stovfl i just started programming a few weeks ago. And i wanted to practice Classes and some OOP... (as im not really good in it)